# Adding fields into a third & fourth field, then subtracting those two fields

Tags: jquery, forms, math

What I have is two sets of form fields.  The first set of fields is added together, and the sum is put into a third field.  The second set does the same thing.  Then, the value of the sums are subtracted from each other and put into a third field.

My problem is that while the first set of fields works fine, the second totally refuses to do anything.  And I'm not sure where to start with the third field.

This is the script that I currently have for the first two sets:

```
$('.assets-add.span3').change(function(){
    var totAssets = 0;
    $.each($('input[class="assets-add span3"]'),function(){
        var assets_val = $(this).val();
        if(assets_val != ""){
            totAssets = totAssets += parseFloat($(this).val());
            $('.totalAssetsField').val(totAssets);
        }
    });
});
$('.loan-add.span3').change(function(){
    var totLoans = 0;
    $.each($('input[class="loan-add"]'),function(){
        var loan_val = $(this).val();
        if(loan_val != ""){
            totLoans = totLoans += parseFloat($(this).val());
            $('.total-liabilities-field').val(totLoans);
        }
    });
});


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see they're virtually identical apart from some class changes and whatever. So I can't figure out why one works and the other doesn't.  And like I said, I don't know where to go with the third field from there, either.

Here's a jsFiddle that probably makes more sense: http://jsfiddle.net/km2hLecb/

Comment: Your selector for the loan inputs is wrong. Try `$.each($('input[class="span3 loan-add"]')`

Answer (score 0):

`class=` compares the entire attribute value, it doesn't just check if an element has the specified class so in your case you'd need to change the selector to

```
input[class="span3 loan-add"]
```

A better way would be to use the class selector syntax like so:

```
$('input.loan-add')
```

Comment: That does fix the issue with the second set, thank you!  Gonna keep messing with it to see if I can get the third field to work.